# How split a dynamic list depends of a number of elements with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, custom-lists, dynamic-list

I have dynamic list with a max number of element (16), I need to split it between one or three columns depends of the following condition: 1-3 elements: 1 column, 4-8elements: 2 columns, 9-16 elements: 3 columns

Comment: What is wrong with using simple if() statements in this case?

Comment: Sounds like fun. What have you tried? What specific problem are you having in implementing this?

Comment: Edit your post, don't put code in comments.

Comment: Your problem still seems to be lacking specifics!

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit strange, your question is interesting (at least to me).
On this page there is a list, if you try to change the number of items and refresh the page, you'll see the elements sorted according to your criteria.
Clearly if you upload the list via ajax, you will need to insert the code in the event done.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<style>
ul.new{float: left;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr=[];
    var len=$('li').length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        var content=$('li:eq('+i+')').html();
        arr.push(content);
        if(i===1||i===3||i===8){
            $('<ul class="new"></ul>').appendTo('body');
            }
        }
    $('#ajax').remove();
    var newLen=$('ul.new').length;
    if(newLen===1){
        for(a=0;a<3;a++){
            if(arr[a]){
                $('<li>'+arr[a]+'</li>').appendTo('ul.new:eq(0)');
                }
            }
        }
    if(newLen===2){
         var firstColumn=Math.round(len/2);
         var secondColumn=len-firstColumn;
         for(x=0;x<firstColumn;x++){
             $('<li>'+arr[x]+'</li>').appendTo('ul.new:eq(0)');
             }  
         for(y=firstColumn;y<len;y++){
             $('<li>'+arr[y]+'</li>').appendTo('ul.new:eq(1)');
            }   
        }
    if(newLen===3){
        var firstColumn=Math.round(len/3);
        var secondColumn=firstColumn;
        var sum=firstColumn+secondColumn;
        var thirdColumn=len-(firstColumn+secondColumn);
        for(x=0;x<firstColumn;x++){
             $('<li>'+arr[x]+'</li>').appendTo('ul.new:eq(0)');
            }   
         for(y=firstColumn;y<sum;y++){
             $('<li>'+arr[y]+'</li>').appendTo('ul.new:eq(1)');
            }
         for(z=sum;z<len;z++){
             $('<li>'+arr[z]+'</li>').appendTo('ul.new:eq(2)');
            }   
        }
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ajax">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>16</li>
    </ul>
  </body>  
</html>
```

If you use ajax the preceding code must be placed within something like

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "your-url.html", 
    type:'get'    
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
    $('body').html($response.find('#ajax'))
   //the code
 });
```

Comment: It's been awhile on this one, but could explain how you're setting the # in each column? I see `i===1||i===8||i===12` but don't fully understand what's going on there. I am hoping to split the lists up in groups of 12. So if there are 14 people, the first group will be 12 and the second just 2, if there are 30 people it would be 2 groups of 12, then the last one of 6, etc.